# How to change pgadmin3 theme

Tags: themes, gtk

Currently I'm using Ambiance-Dark theme, pgadmin look very bad when using this theme (and maybe other dark theme). How to change pgadmin3 theme?

Comment: Superbiji Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: just fixed it posted an answer below

Answer (score 7):

I also use a dark theme and had the same problem. This is how you fix it:

1. If the Server connection is open, close it (right click ->
   Disconnect server)
2. Right click on the Server connection and choose Properties…
3. In the Properties tab click the button in the the second to last
   item, named Colour
4. Select a new colour, say #3C3B37
5. Restart pgAdmin

[image: pgadmin_colour]

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this post](http://www.jkdba.com/pgadmin-one-dark-theme/), here's the settings for `~/.pgadmin3` file so that the sql box looks fine with dark themes

```
[ctlSQLBox]
MarginBackgroundColour=rgb(21, 21, 21)
ColourCaret=rgb(229,192,123)
Colour1=rgb(152, 195, 121)
Colour2=rgb(152, 195, 121)
Colour3=rgb(92, 99, 112)
Colour4=rgb(229, 192, 123)
Colour5=rgb(86, 182, 194)
Colour6=rgb(97, 175, 239)
Colour7=rgb(224, 108, 117)
Colour10=rgb(171, 178, 191)
Colour11=rgb(198, 120, 221)
```

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWRMx.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora with MATE I use the pgadmin.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/interface/gtk-theme "'Adwaita'"
pgadmin3
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/interface/gtk-theme "'BlackMATE'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pgadmin3-gtk you can load a custom gtk theme setting the 
GTK2_RC_FILES env. For example you can load the pgadmin3 with the Adwaita theme running:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc pgadmin3
```

You can then create an alias, a soft link or whatever you want so every time you lunch pgadmin3 it runs with the GTK2_RC_FILES env of the theme that you want.